# Android timer in background services crash app

Tags: java, android, service, handler

Hello I am working with android . I have a background service in my app. I want execute a function in a time interval in background using a timer within the service. When I use a handler.post method, it causes crash my app in some devices. But it works fine in moto G.
Here is my service class

```
public class SyncService extends Service{

    Timer timer;
    Handler handler ;
    SyncData sync_data;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    PrefManager pref;
    DbHelper db;
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    public SyncService() {


    }

    @Override

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");

    }

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        pref= new PrefManager(SyncService.this);
        db=new DbHelper(SyncService.this);
        cd=new ConnectionDetector(SyncService.this);
        sync_data=new SyncData(SyncService.this);


    }

    @Override

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Sync Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        handler= new Handler();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Let it continue running until it is stopped.
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Tracking Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        startTimer();


        return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override

    public void onDestroy() {

        if(timer!=null)
        {
            timer.cancel();
        }



        Toast.makeText(this, "Sync  Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void startTimer() {

        timer = new Timer();


        initializeTimerTask();



    }

    public void initializeTimerTask() {

        timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run()
                    {
                        Log.i("syncc","function excecuted  "+getTime());


                    }

                });

            }

        };

        timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 30 * 1000);

    }
```

and in manifest

```
 <service android:name="mypackage.SyncService" android:process=":my_syn_service" />
```

and it causes error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage.SyncService
```

and error causes at handler line number.

I didn't find the error . How can I fix this problem please help me . Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Your service has both [onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and [onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)). `onStart()` was deprecated in API level 5 and should not be used.  Consider using [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onCreate()) instead. On my KitKat device with `targetSdkVersion` set to 23, the runtime does not even invoke `onStart()` when a call to `startService()` is made.